# Aerospike List operation : how to delete one item from all list bins in a set

Tags: lua, nosql, user-defined-functions, aerospike

I have a Set that have two Bins(pId is long , values is list) and list index is applied on values.
Now i want to remove specify value from values list of all records.

I used `ListOperation.removeByValue` and it's working but it's not fast when records size is more than 100000 records.it's take about 11 seconds to do loop operation.

```
WritePolicy clientWritePolicy = new WritePolicy();
clientWritePolicy.commitLevel = CommitLevel.COMMIT_MASTER;
clientWritePolicy.recordExistsAction = RecordExistsAction.UPDATE;
clientWritePolicy.expiration = 300;
              
Statement statement = new Statement();
statement.setIndexName("values_index");
statement.setNamespace("test");
statement.setSetName("setTest");
               
statement.setFilter(Filter.contains("values", IndexCollectionType.LIST, value));
QueryPolicy queryPolicy = new QueryPolicy();
RecordSet recSet = client.query(queryPolicy, statement);
    
recSet.forEach(rec->{
   client.operate(clientWritePolicy, rec.key,ListOperation.removeByValue("values",Value.get(value), ListReturnType.NONE));
   });
```

How can i optimize this code?is it any other solution like use `UDF`?

update 1:
I wrote below function in `lua` file:

```
function removeListByValue(rec,v)
    local l = list()
    for value in list.iterator(rec["values"]) do
        if(value ~= v) then
             list.append(l, value)
        end
     end
     rec["values"] = l;
     aerospike:update( rec );
end
```

and run it from java client :

```
WritePolicy clientWritePolicy = new WritePolicy();
clientWritePolicy.commitLevel = CommitLevel.COMMIT_MASTER;
clientWritePolicy.recordExistsAction = RecordExistsAction.UPDATE;
clientWritePolicy.expiration = 300;

Statement statement = new Statement();
statement.setIndexName("values_index");
statement.setNamespace("test");
statement.setSetName("setTest");

statement.setFilter(Filter.contains("values", IndexCollectionType.LIST, value));
client.execute(clientWritePolicy, statement, "luaPackage", "removeListByValue",Value.get(value));
```

it seems that `UDF` takes more time to update or remove records.it's about 29 seconds for 200 records.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can apply operations (your ListOperation) in execute instead of using a UDF. You can specify operations in the Statement object using setOperations() and then just use execute(wPolicy, statement).

```
e.g.
Operation[] operations = new Operation[1];
operations[0]= ListOperation.removeByValue(.... 
stmt.setOperations(operations);
WritePolicy wPolicyScan = new WritePolicy();
ExecuteTask et = client.execute(wPolicyScan, stmt)
```

Java API:

execute(WritePolicy policy, Statement statement, Operation... operations)
Apply operations on records that match the background query statement filter

Comment: Thank you @pgupta . i use aerospike-client 4.4.0 version and stmt.setOperations() is in newer version of aerospike client.our aerospike server's version is 5.6.4 .  so i need to change clients version and check your answer.Thanks

Comment: i checked your solution and got "Unexpectedly received bins on background query!" error

Comment: Java client release notes for ver 4.4.6:  - CLIENT-1127 Support write operations in background scan/query. This feature requires server versions >= 4.7.  ( https://download.aerospike.com/download/client/java/notes.html#4.4.6 )

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I was wrong, the aerospike server version was 4.3.1.4 ! Can we upgrade from 4.3.1.4 to 6.1 ? is there any clustering problem for this upgrade? or is it better to upgrade to 5.x version?

Comment: Please follow documentation on upgrades since you are so far behind in your current version! There were significant changes that require you to probably go through certain versions first. See this link: https://docs.aerospike.com/server/operations/upgrade

Answer (score 3):

Thanks @pgupta. I checked your answer on Aerospike Server 5.6.0.7 :

```
    WritePolicy clientWritePolicy = new WritePolicy();
    clientWritePolicy.commitLevel = CommitLevel.COMMIT_MASTER;
    clientWritePolicy.recordExistsAction = RecordExistsAction.REPLACE;
    clientWritePolicy.expiration = 300;
    Statement statement = new Statement();
    statement.setIndexName("values_index");
    statement.setNamespace("test");
    statement.setSetName("setTest");
    statement.setFilter(Filter.contains("values", IndexCollectionType.LIST, value));
    Operation[] operations = new Operation[1];
    operations[0]= ListOperation.removeByValue("values",value, ListReturnType.NONE);
    client.execute(clientWritePolicy, statement,operations);
```

it works.Thank You.

Comment: Thanks for persevering and closing this to successful conclusion.